# Individual color for bootstrap vue progress

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs2, bootstrap-4

Is there any possibility to change the color of a progress bar to any value specified in `hex`?

The colors of variants (e.g. 'success', 'danger') are not fulfilling our specs so I need to specify my own color for the progress like this: `#01A688`.

I already tried to manage via `css` but without success.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is provide a more specific rule targeting the background color of the progress bar.

```css
body{padding: 4rem;}

.progress .progress-bar{background: #01A688;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works. But now I'm missing the striped effect. When I use the class 'progress-bar-striped' nothing happens. Do I have to specify this class on my own?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/progress/), I think you can also do:

```
<b-progress class="">
    <b-progress-bar :style="{ 'background-color': '#01A688' }" :value="25"></b-progress-bar>
</b-progress>
```

Answer (score 0):

I put the .progress-bar styling in global CSS (not the scoped one) and it worked. More specifically, I put the following in _style.css:

```
.progress-bar {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```